# ArrayList If Loop not working properly: JAVA

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I have a program that asks the user their name etc. Then it asks how many times do you want the numbers to loop (so my program generates 3 random numbers between 7 and 13 and if it adds up to 31 they are the winner) and my issue is that I only want the last printed number to count towards if the player wins or looses, the other numbers are just for show or tease i guess. the problem is that regardless towards if the player wins or looses, the losing statement always prints out. Below is my entire code.

```
 import java.util.InputMismatchException;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.Random;

 public class StringVariables {



public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException,
        IOException {

    // user inputs their name in this section
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
 //enter their first name

    String first_name;
    System.out.print("Enter Your First Name: ");
    while
        (!user_input.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")) {
        System.out.println("Please only enter alphabet characters. Try again.");
        user_input.next();
    }
    first_name = user_input.next();

 //enter their last name
    String last_name;
    System.out.print("Enter Your Last Name: ");
    while
        (!user_input.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")) {
        System.out.println("Please only enter alphabet characters. Try again.");
        user_input.next();
    }
    last_name = user_input.next();
  //full name printed together
    String full_name;
    full_name = first_name + " " + last_name;

    System.out.println(full_name + " Is Now Playing");

    // this is the shuffle portion as well as something to see if a number

    int numShuffles = -1;
    while (numShuffles < 0) {

        System.out.println("How many times do you want the numbers shuffled? ");

        try {
            numShuffles = user_input.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException inputException) {
            System.out.print("Please enter a valid number. \n");
            //this is the buffer that resets if the user types a letter instead of a number, or any other character
            user_input.next();
        }
    } 

    // here is going to be the loop for shuffles

    // we are now going to generate their random number and add a delay
    // after completing their name fields

    delay(3000);
    System.out
            .println(" You will be given " + numShuffles +  " hand(s) of 3 random numbers between 7-13" );

    delay(2000);
    System.out
            .println(" Then, the computer will add the random numbers and if it is equal to 31, you win!");

    /*
     * end of explanation of the game, next i will create a new screen with
     * the user's name and numbers
     */

    delay(4000);
    // printing 25 blank lines
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        System.out.println(" ");


    System.out.println("User playing: " + full_name);

    System.out.println("Number of times shuffled: " + numShuffles);

    System.out.println("Your lucky numbers are...");

    // random number generator

    Random random = new Random();



    while (true) {

        // the shuffle loop
        Arraylist numberStore = new Arraylist();
        boolean isWinner = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numShuffles; i++) {
            int num1 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);
            int num2 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);
            int num3 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);

            System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " + " + num3 + " = " + (num1 + num2 + num3));
            numberStore.add(num1 + num2 + num3);


        int lastNumber = (numberStore.size() - 1);
        if (lastNumber == 31) {
                isWinner = true;
                System.out.println("Congratulations !! You are the Lucky Winner !!!!");
                break;
                //if you loose every shuffle
        }
        }
       if (!isWinner) {
            System.out.println("Better Luck Next Time");
       }
        // play again prompt
        System.out
                .println(" Do you want to play again? (If you do enter y or yes) \n To exit press any other key ");
        String input = user_input.next();
        if (!"y".equalsIgnoreCase(input) && !"yes".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // if pressed y or yes the program will run again with the same number of shuffles entered from before
    user_input.close();
}

// delay field

public static void delay(int millis) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (InterruptedException exp) {

        // delay field

    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Um? `int lastNumber = (numberStore.size() - 1);`

Comment: First of all , it is ArrayList and not Arraylist ...Typo i guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                 int lastNumber = (numberStore.size() - 1);
                 if (lastNumber == 31) {
```

you probably want something like

```
                 int lastNumber = numberStore.get(numberStore.size() - 1);
                 if (lastNumber == 31) {
```

to verify that is the error try to change that line to

```
                 int lastNumber = num1 + num2 + num3;
```

Edit based on further messages:

Looks like what you really want is this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numShuffles; i++) {
        int num1 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);
        int num2 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);
        int num3 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);


        System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " + " + num3 + " = " + (num1 + num2 + num3));
        numberStore.add(num1 + num2 + num3);


        int lastNumber = num1 + num2 + num3;

        boolean lastShuffle = (i == (numShuffles - 1));
        if (lastShuffle) {
            if (lastNumber == 31) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations !! You are the Lucky Winner !!!!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Better Luck Next Time");
            }
        }
    }
    // play again prompt
    System.out
        .println(" Do you want to play again? (If you do enter y or yes) \n To exit press any other key ");
    String input = user_input.next();
    if (!"y".equalsIgnoreCase(input) && !"yes".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
        break;
    }
```

Just a general suggestion: avoid to use break if possible, it makes control flow hard to follow and is not a good programming practice.

Comment: yes but what i need is only the last 3 numbers to count, not if one in the loop does. only the last 3 numbers printed out

Comment: Add this:                  if (lastNumber == 31 && i==(numShuffles=1))

Comment: it still prints out the loser string even if the last 3 numbers are equal to 31. im completely stumped on this

Comment: did you try with                  int lastNumber = num1 + num2 + num3;
and  if (lastNumber == 31 && i==(numShuffles-1)) ? (note there is a typo in the comment above)

Comment: it works... i just have one more thing to ask from you. is it possible to make it so it doesn't print out the loser code on every loop of numbers?

Comment: if you dont exactly understand the code prints as
Your lucky numbers are...
13 + 9 + 9 = 31


Better Luck Next Time


12 + 9 + 10 = 31


Better Luck Next Time


11 + 9 + 7 = 27


Better Luck Next Time


12 + 9 + 7 = 28


Better Luck Next Time


9 + 9 + 10 = 28


Better Luck Next Time

Comment: change it like this: boolean lastShuffle = (i==(numShuffles-1)); if (lastShuffle){ if (lastNumber == 31) {printWin(); } else {printLose();}} 

Remember to accept the answer!

Comment: do you think you could edit that into the code above? im not able to figure out how to input it properly

Comment: there you go :)

Answer (score 0):

Several points to make here. One, your code is quite messy and hard to read. It's helpful when you're asking for help (and in general anyway) to properly indent your code. This is good practice and if you do other languages like Python can help you out a lot. Also, why do a check for !isWinner? Scrap the isWinner variable altogether and just check for the number equalling 31 and then have an else statement for the losing statement. Like this:

```
    if (lastNumber == 31) {
        System.out.println("Congratulations !! You are the Lucky Winner !!!!");
        break;
        //if you loose every shuffle
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Better Luck Next Time");
    }
```

Also, take some steps to find the error. Print out each number as you get it, and use

```
int lastNumber = num1 + num2 + num3;
```

instead of

```
int lastNumber = (numberStore.size() - 1);
```

Also for anybody else compiling this, it's **ArrayList** and not **Arraylist**... just a little slip.

Comment: the problem with this though is that after every line of the 3 numbers printed out it tells me if it is a loser or not, and if it is the winner it stops the loop the user inputted completely. i remember being at this stage before but i cant figure out how to just get the last number to count as a winner or loser

Comment: Let me see if I can get what you're asking here (I find your wording a bit unclear). You want it so that only the last of the 3 numbers being added count towards winning / losing?

Comment: yes. sorry i know my wording is hard to understand. only the last 3 numbers of the loop should count towards winning or loosing. the others are just "for show" kind of like if you only did 4 shuffles you would of won, to put it more into a better perspective.

Comment: do you know how to do that? @brld

Comment: Alright, it's not compiling for me for some reason on my IDE so I'll try to debug this with you. First make the loop that generates numbers go until it is less than 3 and not number of shuffles. And also move the following code that sets the amount and checks if you have won to outside of the loop. This is just for debugging. Let me know your results.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I may have to say that your codes are a kind of mess up. a small factory with the solution you ask, hope it can be a little help to you

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException,
        IOException {
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String full_name = registeGamePlayer(user_input);
    int numShuffles = initGame(user_input);
    showTheGameInfo(full_name, numShuffles);
    runningGame(user_input, numShuffles);
    user_input.close();
}

/**
 * @param user_input
 * @param numShuffles
 */
private static void runningGame(Scanner user_input, int numShuffles) {
    // random number generator
    Random random = new Random();
    while (true) {
        // the shuffle loop
        boolean isWinner = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numShuffles; i++) {
            int num1 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);
            int num2 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);
            int num3 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);

            int amount = num1 + num2 + num3;
            System.out.printf("%d + %d + %d = %d \n", num1,num2,num3,amount);
            if (amount == 31) {
                isWinner = true;
                System.out.println("Congratulations !! You are the Lucky Winner !!!!");
                break;
                // if you loose every shuffle
            }
        }
        if (!isWinner) {
            System.out.println("Better Luck Next Time");
        }
        // play again prompt
        System.out.println(" Do you want to play again? (If you do enter y or yes) \n To exit press any other key ");
        String input = user_input.next();
        if (!"y".equalsIgnoreCase(input) && !"yes".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @param full_name
 * @param numShuffles
 */
private static void showTheGameInfo(String full_name, int numShuffles) {
    // printing 25 blank lines
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        System.out.println(" ");

    System.out.println("User playing: " + full_name);

    System.out.println("Number of times shuffled: " + numShuffles);

    System.out.println("Your lucky numbers are...");
}

// delay field

public static void delay(int millis) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (InterruptedException exp) {

        // delay field

    }
}

private static String registeGamePlayer(Scanner user_input){
    String first_name;
    System.out.print("Enter Your First Name: ");
    while (!user_input.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")) {
        System.out
                .println("Please only enter alphabet characters. Try again.");
        user_input.next();
    }
    first_name = user_input.next();

    // enter their last name
    String last_name;
    System.out.print("Enter Your Last Name: ");
    while (!user_input.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")) {
        System.out
                .println("Please only enter alphabet characters. Try again.");
        user_input.next();
    }
    last_name = user_input.next();
    // full name printed together
    String full_name;
    full_name = first_name + " " + last_name;

    System.out.println(full_name + " Is Now Playing");

    return full_name;
}

private static int initGame(Scanner user_input){
    // this is the shuffle portion as well as something to see if a number

            int numShuffles = -1;
            while (numShuffles < 0) {
                System.out.println("How many times do you want the numbers shuffled? ");
                try {
                    numShuffles = user_input.nextInt();
                } catch (InputMismatchException inputException) {
                    System.out.print("Please enter a valid number. \n");
                    // this is the buffer that resets if the user types a letter
                    // instead of a number, or any other character
                    user_input.next();
                }
            }
            // here is going to be the loop for shuffles

            // we are now going to generate their random number and add a delay
            // after completing their name fields

            delay(3000);
            System.out.println(" You will be given " + numShuffles + " hand(s) of 3 random numbers between 7-13");

            delay(2000);
            System.out.println(" Then, the computer will add the random numbers and if it is equal to 31, you win!");

            /*
             * end of explanation of the game, next i will create a new screen with
             * the user's name and numbers
             */

            delay(4000);
            return numShuffles;
}
```

Comment: i tried popping this code into eclipse but i ended up getting tons of errors, did overflow format your code wrong or an error of somesort?

Comment: you need to import the necessary class: import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;    please create a new class, and then cope the above codes into your class with the imports I just attached

Comment: the issue arrises as i only want the last 3 numbers to be counted as either a winner or loser, if it is a winner before the loop the user creates ends and wont fulfill the full number of cards they wanted to be drawn out. i know its complicated. but only the last number that gets printed should count as if it wins or looses. your coding looks beautiful by the way.

Comment: what you means that the last 3 numbers,  could you give a clear example? I am confusing

Comment: I think that I may get what you want, if the numShuffles is 1, the last three number will be num1 , num2 and num3 from the loop. if the numShuffles is 2, the last three number will be number from second loop. is that right?

Comment: yes but im just having the issue now of the losing code being printed out on every line of the shuffle loop. i have figured out how to get only the last 3 numbers in the shuffle to count i just need to figure out how to get rid of the losing prints when they shouldnt be there

Comment: you can add the if(i+1 < numShuffles) continue; after this line : int num3 = 7 + random.nextInt(7);